# I want to add a button if the body width is max 500px

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever i try to resize my browser window , the button appears several times
, How can i fix that. I want that if the browser is resized to 500px or less
there should be div added and if the width is above the 500px the div should be removed . Here is the JS file

```
function sizer(){const mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width:500px)" )

if(mq.matches)
{
 let loginDiv= document.createElement('div'),
     aTag = document.createElement('a');
     aTag.setAttribute('href','#');
     aTag.innerHTML="Login/Sign Up";
     loginDiv.className='login';// style in search.css
     document.getElementsByClassName('drp')[0].appendChild(loginDiv);
     loginDiv.appendChild(aTag);

}
else{
  document.getElementsByClassName("login").remove();
}
}
```

Here Sizer is called from the body tag as below

```
<body onresize="sizer()">
```

[Picture of viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/959ah.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media query `@media (max-width: 500px)` to show/hide the button conditionally based on the screen width. There is no need to use Javascript for such use-cases.

```css
#myButton {
  display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #myButton {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
Click me
</button>
```

For JS, you can use `$(window).on("resize",...` handler like this:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  console.log("Resizing: ", window.innerWidth);
  if(window.innerWidth < 500) {
    $("#myButton").show();
  } else {
    $("#myButton").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">
Click me
</button>
```

To inject the element dynamically into DOM based on window width:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  console.log("Resizing: ", window.innerWidth);
  if(window.innerWidth < 500) {
    if($("#myDiv > #myButton").length == 0) {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerText = "Click me";
      button.id = "myButton";
    
      $("#myDiv").append(button);
    }
  } else {
    $("#myButton").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  Div.
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add a button dynamically using javascript only

Comment: @ParasKumar Updated my answer to show how you could use the `resize` event. Note that if you wish to insert the element dynamically, you can use `document.createElement("button")` and then append it to body.

Comment: The problem with inserting the element dynaically is that it is going on adding the button till this statement is true `if(window.innerWidth < 500)` and i only want it to add the button once .

Comment: @ParasKumar I have added a third example showing how you could do this. Basically, you need to identify a way of checking whether the button is already added to dom before inserting it.